# Permutation combination problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

This is how Edward’s Lotteries work. First, 9 different numbers are selected. Tickets with exactly 6
of the 9 numbers randomly selected are printed such that no two tickets have the same set of numbers.
Finally, the winning ticket is the one containing the 6 numbers drawn from the 9 randomly. There is
exactly one winning ticket in the lottery system. How many tickets can the lottery system print?

Comment: Have you learned about binomial coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of tickets is the number of ways to **choose** $6$ numbers from $9$.

How do we calculate that that number? It is simplest if we know a *formula* for the binomial coefficient $\binom{9}{6}$ aka $C(9,6)$ aka $C^9_6$. One expression for this is $\frac{9!}{6!3!}$. Now we compute. There is a lot of cancellation.

Or we can figure out the number from first principles. How many ways are there to choose $6$ numbers (the ones that will appear on tickets) from $9$? Just as many as there are ways to choose the $3$ numbers that *don't* appear. (Yhis "feels" easier, since $3$ is smaller than $6$.)

There are $(9)(8)(7)$ three number **strings** made up of different numbers. The $6$ strings $abc,acb, bac,bca,cab,cba$ all represent the same ticket, the same choice of rejected numbers. So the total number of tickets we can print is $\frac{(9)(8)(7)}{6}$.